# Batch Normalizaton before or after activation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, batch-normalization

Can someone kindly explain what are the benefits and disadvantages of applying Batch Normalisation before or after Activation Functions? I know that popular practice is to normalize before activation, but I am interested to know what are the positives/ negatives of the above two approaches?